# How to wait for specific String in TextView to proceed to next method

Tags: java, android

I've just started learning so please be tolerant.

I want to constantly check if my TextView is equal to "tata", and then to doStuff(), but can't figure out how to do it...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);


    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


    // SyllableButtonListener appends TextView only if 
    // button.getText().equals("ta")


    button1.setOnClickListener(new SyllableButtonListener(tv, "ta", button1));
    button2.setOnClickListener(new SyllableButtonListener(tv, "ta", button2));
    button3.setOnClickListener(new SyllableButtonListener(tv, "ta", button3));

    // how to do it: ???
    // if(tv.getText.equals("tata")){ doStuff() }


}
```

any kind of loops dosen't work. I've tried with Thread, but it's not working well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText`

```
//considering it as a EditText instead of Textview since you would know when textView text changes to "tata"
```

New Code

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if(s.toString().equals("tata")) {
             //do stuff
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your post your textview is frequently changing text. At the time pressing a button get the text view instance and check for your text.
you have to implement onClick(View v) method.

```
public void onClick(View v){
   //here v is the button view.
   //you have to use the textview instance which you have already created in onCreate method
    if(textView.getText().equals("YourText"){
      //do your stuff
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need che id "tata" string is contained in textView
Can you try:

```
teextView.getText().contains("tata")
```